# Error while selecting rows from pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with the column `Name`. I did:

```
for name in df['Name'].unique ():
        X = df[df['Name'] == name]
print (X.head())
```

but then X contains all kinds of different `Name`, not an unique name I want.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your solution should work (better is use `groupby`), can you add some data sample?

Comment: Also why need loop this way? Maybe here is possible non loop solution.

Comment: Or maybe indentation problem of `print (X.head())`, need add spaces before for code start under `X = df[df['Name'] == name]`

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to overwrite `X` with every iteration of your loop and only keep the dataframe containing the last value of `df['Name'].unique()`.

Depending on your data and goal, you might want to use `groupby` as jezrael suggests, or maybe do something like `df[~df['Name'].duplicated()]`.